# AD Update from CSV file without SamAccountName

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

My goal is to use a CSV file exported by HR without the correct headings to update our AD Users&Computers. Ultimately I would like to update:  Department, Description/Job Title, Office, Location, Manager.

I'm not asking you to do this for me, just point me in the right direction and id be really grateful.

Also you will notice there is no SamAccountName, this is by design, because users have the same name so we have had to use the first 2 initials of some users first name followed by the last name.

```
import-module ActiveDirectory
Import-CSV $data | ForEach-Object {
     $Name;expression={($_.'First Name'+' '+$_.'Last Name')}
     $displayName;expression={$_.'First Name'+' '+$_.'Last Name'}
     $givenName;expression={$_.'First Name'}
     $surName;expression={$_.'Last Name'}
     $description;expression={$_.'Job Name'}
     $office;expression={$_.'Location Name'}
     $department;expression={$_.'Department Name'}
     $title;expression={$_.'Job Name'}
     $manager;expression={$_.'Manager Name'} 
     }
foreach ($user in $data){
Get-ADUser -Filter "displayName -eq '$($user.$Name)'" | Set-ADUser -Replace @{title = “$($user.$title)”}
}
```

One of the errors I am getting

```
The term 'expression=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell us what went wrong ? :) I see at least some weird quotes in the end

Comment: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/

Comment: @sodawillow Those would be smart quotes. _Usually_ a product of copy and paste. And Cam you never actually asked a question?

Comment: You are not assigning a value to `$name` (or the other variables) so I am sure you are getting several errors in that regard. `$Name = $_.'First Name' + ' ' + $_.'Last Name'` among the other issues I see you have here. You don't need to have two loops and `$data` looks like a file path so It would have no weight in the second for each loop

Comment: Just for the record... no matter if people have the same names, sAMAccountName could be 'roflninjacopter' for John Doe, 'kitten27'  for Neo and so on... Oh and while on the subject of same names; finding a user where the displayName -eq "First Name" + "Last Name" - couldn't that possibly make the CIO a groundskeeper or similar?

Comment: Hey Everyone, thank you for responding. Sorry for the inadequate question. My question is where am I going wrong. Also I know I shouldn't be using 2 loops, but I don't know the syntax of how to put it together in one loop :-/ @ the sAMAccountName, our accounts are set with users first initial of their first name followed by their last name. But the problem is some users have the same first initial and last name so we have had to use the first two initials. That all being said, i was just trying to make this as simple as possible without really having to use check, because thats beyond me :(

Comment: So far, theres are the errors im receiving.          
expression= : The term 'expression=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again. 

At C:\scripts\bulk_update.ps1:12 char:19
+          $manager;expression={$_.'Manager Name'}
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (expression=:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: import-module ActiveDirectory
$data = Import-CSV "C:\scripts\ADIntegrationData.csv" | ForEach-Object {
         $Name ;expression={($_.'First Name'+' '+$_.'Last Name')}
         $samAccountName;expression={($_.'First   Name'.substring(0,1)+$_.'Last Name').toLower()}
         $displayName;expression={$_.'First Name'+' '+$_.'Last Name'}
         $givenName;expression={$_.'First Name'}
         $surName;expression={$_.'Last Name'}
         $description;expression={$_.'Job Name'}
         $department;expression={$_.'Department Name'}

Comment: $office;epression={$_.'Location Name'}
         $title;expression={$_.'Job Name'}
         $manager;expression={$_.'Manager Name'} 
         }
foreach ($user in $data){
Get-ADUser -Filter “displayName -eq ‘$($user.$Name)'” | Set-ADUser -Replace @{title = $($user.$title)}
}

Comment: Sorry its so ugly and not formatted

Comment: @Cam That's why you should edit your question instead of posting relevant information as comments.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Sorry about that, first time posting, appreciate the tips, not being facetious.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for the most part is unmanageable. It is easier to redo it in order to

> point [you] in the right direction

You over complicated things by trying to rename your values of each row. While you can do that you don't really need to. FWIW you were throwing in syntax from [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Path to the CSV file
$filePath = "C:\scripts\ADIntegrationData.csv"

# Import the users
Import-CSV $filePath | ForEach-Object {

    # Try and find a matching user
    $displayName = "{0} {1}" -f $_.'First Name', $_.'Last Name'
    Get-ADUser Get-ADUser -Filter "displayName -eq '$displayName'" | Set-ADUser -Title $_.'Job Name' -WhatIf
}
```

In the case of [`Set-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617215.aspx) you only have to use the `-Add`, `-Remove` and `-Replace` if the property you want to change is already present. `-Title` is already support so in that case we use it! Always consult the documentation so check the link for [`Set-ADUser`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617215.aspx) and look at the attributes that are natively available to change.

You will see the [`-f` formatting operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) used here. It is a simple way to work with building complicated strings.

Notice the `-WhatIf` which will help you test your code before making changes to AD that might be wrong.

Comment: Hey Matt, Thank you for your response just one qq, at the Set-ADUser, if i wanted to expand the import to allow for multiple parameters, could i just add them before the -WhatIf statement? ie Set-ADUser -Title $_.'Job Name'  -Department $_.'Department Name' -WhatIf
}

Comment: It does not _have_ to be before the `-whatif`. But yeah... just add them in there.  @Cam